# How to convert Hexadecimal schedule string to date time format

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, hex

I have a table in our database that lists schedules for updating sccm collections on a cycle.  The schedules look like they are in a hexadecimal format.  The schedules are kind of like a scheduled task format.  Example I have the schedule is set to `start 8/14/2020 at 4:00 AM local time and recur every 7 days.`  In the database it is shown as `008E8C8000100038`.  I'm wondering if there is an easy way to convert this to a readable date time value so can view schedules actually when querying.  The column just shows as string so I haven't had any luck with trying to convert it directly to date time.

Comment: You're in a much better position to know how the data is encoded then we are! You need to find out/work out how the data is being encoded when its added. We are unable to assist with that.

Comment: Looks like an SCCM Schedule String. Have you tried running it through the [ConvertFrom-CCMSchedule](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSCCMClient/0.2.0/Content/Public%5CConvertFrom-CCMSchedule.ps1) PowerShell function? You could probably convert that to SQL without too much effort.

Comment: Okay.  I assumed it was using some SQL standard of format to encode it that could be converted.  Ya I know I can use PowerShell to get the schedule but then its outside the query.  Ill just use PowerShell itself if I cant build a query around it. Thanks.